# mount CIFS volume with pam_mount and password stored in gnome-keyring

Tags: linux, cifs, gnome-keyring, pam-mount

I would like to store the passwords for CIFS volumes in gnome-keyring.

I am currently using a text file with credentials in it and passing that to pam mount / mount.cifs which then will mount the share.  Is there anyway to store the credentials in an encrypted form so they are at least a little harder to get to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I chose ecryptfs. You simply create an encrypted directory where the files are stored.
See [RedHat's Instructions](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/filesysnew-efs.html). If you encrypt this file with the user's password, there is even the possibility to mount this directory automatically at login with pam_mount (also name of the package in fedora 15). The pam_mount setup is a bit finicky though.

My advice here: follow the instructions of the manual pages to setup [pam_mount](http://web.iesrodeira.com/cgi-bin/man/man2html?8%20pam_mount) in pam.d. pam_mount will eventually use mount (mount.ecryptfs, respectively). So setup fstab in a way that your user can mount this fs without problems from the command line (possibly without root privileges). Then read pam_mount.conf, set debug=2 in the pam_mount.conf.xml reduce the requirements in pam_mount.conf to a minimum and follow the instructions in the pam_mount.conf.xml template to create a local copy.

You can test by logging in an out on a console.